# Spring Boot banner.gif is not animated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Spring Boot 2 feature with an animated banner, but unfortunately, in my case, all the gifs are shown just like a list of images that are just going one after another:

```
                            .::::::::::::::*                              
                       *:::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                 *::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*                   
               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*               
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  *           
           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*:           
          :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*. :.          
         ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*.     *.          
        ::::::::::::::::.             .::::::::::***.         *:          
        :::::::::::::                                         ::          
       .:::::::::::                                           ::*         
       :::::::::::                                            :::         
       ::::::::::                                      .      :::         
       :::::::::*                                    :       .:::         
       .::::::::.                                  :*        :::*         
        :::::::::                              *::.         .:::          
        :::::::::.                         ::::*           .::::          
         :::::::::*....             .*:::::::              ::::           
          ::::.   ::::::::::::::::::::::.                 ::::            
           :::.  .::::*****......                       *::::             
            ::::::::::::::::*                         *:::::              
             .::::::::::::::::::::.                 ::::::*               
               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       *:::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            .::::::::::::::*                              







                            .::::::::::::::*                              
                       *:::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::    .            
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*.*:*           
            :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*. :           
           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*    :           
          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*       :           
         ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*.           **          
        :::::::::::::::::*                                    .:          
        :::::::::::::*                                         :          
       .:::::::::::.                                           :*         
       :::::::::::                                     *       ::         
       ::::::::::                                     :       .::         
       :::::::::.                                   *:        *::         
       .::::::::                                  ::          ::*         
        ::::::::                               :::           .::          
        ::::::::*                          *::::             :::          
         ::::::::                      ::::::.              :::           
          :::::::::       ..**::::::::::::                 :::            
           ::::*..::::::::::::::::::*.                   *:::             
            :::    :::::**.                            *::::              
             .:*..*:::::::::::**                    .:::::*               
               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       *:::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            *::::::::::::::*                              







                            .::::::::::::::*                              
                       *:::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::     *.            
               :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: .:*:            
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*  :            
            :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::    .:           
           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*       :           
          :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.          :.          
         ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*.               .:          
        ::::::::::::::::::*                                    :          
        ::::::::::::::.                                        :          
       .::::::::::::                                    .      :*         
       :::::::::::                                     *       ::         
       ::::::::::                                    :*        ::         
       :::::::::*                                   :*         ::         
       .::::::::                                 :::          .:*         
        ::::::::                               :::            ::          
        ::::::::                           .::::             .::          
         ::::::::                       ::::::               ::           
          ::::::::               .:::::::::                *::            
           :::::::::.**::::::::::::::::                   :::             
            ::::.  :::::::::::::.                       ::::              
             .:.    ::::*.                           :::::*               
               :. .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            .::::::::::::::.                              







                            .::::::::::::::.                              
                       *:::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::        *             
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::    ::             
               ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*: .:            
             .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::    :            
            :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.     .:           
           ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::         :           
          :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::             **          
         ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*                   :          
        *::::::::::::::::::.                                   :          
        :::::::::::::::                                 .      :.         
       .::::::::::::                                           *:         
       :::::::::::.                                   *        *:         
       ::::::::::                                    :         *:         
       :::::::::*                                  .:          ::         
       .::::::::                                 :::           :*         
        ::::::::                               :::            .:          
        *:::::::                            ::::              ::          
         :::::::.                       *:::::               ::           
          :::::::                  .:::::::.                ::            
           ::::::::       .*:::::::::::*                  :::             
            ::::::::::::::::::::::*                     ::::              
             .::    ::::::::.                       .:::::*               
               :    *::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       *:::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            .::::::::::::::*                              







                            .::::::::::::::*                              
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::       :.             
                 *::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*   :*:             
               :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  *:            
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.    :            
            :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::      .:           
           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::          :           
          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.             *:          
         :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*                    :          
        :::::::::::::::::::*                                   :          
        :::::::::::::::                                 *      ::         
       .::::::::::::                                   *       .:         
       :::::::::::.                                   :         :         
       ::::::::::                                    :         .:         
       ::::::::::                                  ::          *:         
       .::::::::                                 :::           :*         
        ::::::::                               :::             :          
        ::::::::                            ::::              ::          
         :::::::                         :::::               *:           
          :::::::                   ::::::::                ::            
           :::::::.         .:::::::::::                  :::             
            :::::::::::::::::::::::.                    ::::              
             .:::   :::::::::*                      .:::::*               
               :     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 ..*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            .::::::::::::::*                              







                            *::::::::::::::*                              
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::       :.             
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::   :*:             
               :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  *:            
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::     :            
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.      .:           
           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::          :           
          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::              *:          
         :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*                    :          
        :::::::::::::::::::*                                   :          
        :::::::::::::::                                 *      *:         
       .::::::::::::                                   *       .:         
       :::::::::::.                                   :         :         
       ::::::::::                                    :         .:         
       ::::::::::                                  ::          .:         
       .::::::::                                 :::           :*         
        ::::::::                               :::             :          
        ::::::::                            ::::              ::          
         :::::::                         :::::               *:           
          :::::::                   *:::::::                ::            
           :::::::.          :::::::::::                  :::             
            :::::::::::::::::::::::*                    ::::              
             .:::   :::::::::*                      .:::::*               
               :     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 . .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            *::::::::::::::*                              







                            *::::::::::::::*                              
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::       :.             
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::   :*:             
               :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  *:            
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::     :            
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.      .:           
           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::          :           
          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::              *:          
         :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*                    :          
        :::::::::::::::::::*                                   :          
        :::::::::::::::                                 *      *:         
       .::::::::::::                                   *       .:         
       :::::::::::.                                   :         :         
       ::::::::::                                    :         .:         
       ::::::::::                                  ::          .:         
       .::::::::                                 :::           :*         
        ::::::::                               :::             :          
        ::::::::                            ::::              ::          
         :::::::                         :::::               *:           
          :::::::                   *:::::::                ::            
           :::::::.          :::::::::::                  :::             
            :::::::::::::::::::::::*                    ::::              
             .:::   :::::::::*                      .:::::*               
               :     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 . .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            *::::::::::::::*                              







                            *::::::::::::::*                              
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::       :.             
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::   :*:             
               :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  *:            
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::     :            
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.      .:           
           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::          :           
          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::              *:          
         :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*                    :          
        :::::::::::::::::::*                                   :          
        :::::::::::::::                                 *      *:         
       .::::::::::::                                   *       .:         
       :::::::::::.                                   :         :         
       ::::::::::                                    :         .:         
       ::::::::::                                  ::          .:         
       .::::::::                                 :::           :*         
        ::::::::                               :::             :          
        ::::::::                            ::::              ::          
         :::::::                         :::::               *:           
          :::::::                   *:::::::                ::            
           :::::::.          :::::::::::                  :::             
            :::::::::::::::::::::::*                    ::::              
             .:::   :::::::::*                      .:::::*               
               :     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 . .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            *::::::::::::::*                              







                            *::::::::::::::*                              
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::       :.             
                 *:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::   :*:             
               :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  *:            
             .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::     :            
            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.      .:           
           :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::          :           
          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::              *:          
         :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*                    :          
        :::::::::::::::::::*                                   :          
        :::::::::::::::                                 *      *:         
       .::::::::::::                                   *       .:         
       :::::::::::.                                   :         :         
       ::::::::::                                    :         .:         
       ::::::::::                                  ::          .:         
       .::::::::                                 :::           :*         
        ::::::::                               :::             :          
        ::::::::                            ::::              ::          
         :::::::                         :::::               *:           
          :::::::                   *:::::::                ::            
           :::::::.          :::::::::::                  :::             
            :::::::::::::::::::::::*                    ::::              
             .:::   :::::::::*                      .:::::*               
               :     ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                 
                 . .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                   
                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                      
                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::                         
                            *::::::::::::::*
```

Now I am running app in docker, but it works the same way for me while I run app locally as well. Do you have any ideas on why it doesn't work as it should? 
My spring boot parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: I can see it animating - if i scroll up and down xD

Comment: ahaha exactly! :)

Comment: Puhhh, animated banner is an issue for you ? you're a lucky dveloper !! (SCNR) Anyway, you are talking about the console (stdout) banner (?). And your console supports anim GIFs ??

Comment: It's not actually a GIF, Spring Boot 2 uses a library under the hood to convert it to ASCII. Example: https://github.com/longfeizheng/animated-banner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is as PeterMmmm suspected, your console needs to be able to animate the gif. For example if I run the program via my IDE the gif is rendered as a slideshow, just like in your case.

If I start the program on linux via ./gifBanner.jar the gif is animated in my terminal window.

Comment: Hopefully, Jetbrains will add this support to their terminal(if it's not a default one from the system). Cause it's a crucial feature.